# Strip out all &nbsp; from the excerpt in WP

Tags: php, wordpress, function, filter

I have the following code in my WP functions.php file:

```
function custom_excerpt($new_length = 22, $new_more = ' ...') {

add_filter('excerpt_length', function () use ($new_length) {
return $new_length;
}, 999);

add_filter('excerpt_more', function () use ($new_more) {
return $new_more;
});

$output = get_the_excerpt();
$output = apply_filters('wptexturize', $output);
$output = apply_filters('convert_chars', $output);
$output = '<p>' . $output . '</p>';
echo $output;
}
```

I than use the following code to displat it:

```
 php custom_excerpt(50, ' ...');
```

My question is: How to get rid of all the "nbsp;" entities from all my excerpts on my WP page?

Comment: Can't you just do $output = str_replace('&nbsp;','',$output);

Comment: Is [str_replace()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) not working out for you?